# Why does float64 allow NA, but int32 does not?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({a:[1,2], b:[None,3]})
df.dtypes
```

Outputs:

```
a      int64
b    float64
```

Then:

```
df.b.astype(int)
```

Outputs:

```
*** ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer
```

In general I would expect if one numeric type accepts NA (e.g. float64), then all would accept NA. What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: There is a long decision reason by all of [this](http://www.numpy.org/NA-overview.html#designs-that-have-been-proposed), basically it's something that currently isn't supported for integer types

Comment: integer uses all it's bits to represent a value. no bit left for NA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is based on how the numbers are represented. Floats are [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), which define specific bit patterns that represent `NaN` or "Not a Number." Integers usually have a much simpler representation, and have no concept of `NaN`.

The Pandas docs contain a [more extended discussion](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#nan-integer-na-values-and-na-type-promotions) of the issue.